# How to create custom design for AEM Communities

Tags: aem, aem-6, hbs

I have created a community website using AEM Communities. While creating the site, I can see some bootstrap designs and a we retail design. Now I would like to create my own template which uses the client libs that I have so I can use my components to customise the website. I am not sure how to do this.

I have edited the .hbs file `/libs/social/console/components/hbs/sitepage/sitepage.hbs` but there is no change that I can see. The documentation [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/communities/develop/overlay-alter-appearance.html?lang=en) also don't describe much about creating custom designs. It would be very much helpful if someone can help here. If I am able to find the file to overwrite, I think I can copy it to apps and it will be shown as a new design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never make a change in /libs - copy it to /apps and change it there. the /apps version will override the /libs version.

To add a design, follow the documentation here:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/introduction/designer.html?lang=en

They don't recommend doing this as you have to use the classic UI. But you still can, and it still works.